# can't start mysql due to: Manager of pid-file quit without updating file

Tags: linux, mysql, centos

I can't start mysql due to this error:

```
 ERROR! MySQL manager or server PID file could not be found!
Starting MySQL.. ERROR! Manager of pid-file quit without updating file.
```

how can I fix this please?

Comment: You should take a look at the error log: `/var/log/mysqld.log`.

Comment: Thanks, it a cPanel server. cat: /var/log/mysqld.log: No such file or directory

Comment: `grep error /etc/my.cnf`?

Comment: Insert it (`log-error      = /var/log/mysqld.log`) into the `[mysqld]` section then try again and post the log here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the OS - the MySQL logs will be in varying locations and not always what is dictated in `my.cnf`.

`Debian` for example will put them in `/var/log/syslog`

`CentOS/Redhat` will put them in `/var/lib/mysql/__hostname__.err`

etc.

But you can actually just start the MySQL daemon without using `service` or `init.d` and just execute the command directly. This will print any/all of your errors to `stdout`

Eg. `mysqld`

Typically, for the error you have, it is because of permissions issues with the MySQL daemon being able to write to the pid file.

`Debian` will put them in `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid`

`CentOS/Redhat` will put them in `/var/lib/mysql/mysql.pid`